# dbxtool: debug executable and run with arguments

Tags: debugging, unix

How can I debug an executable and run with arguments in dbxtool from the command line in unix? According to the help it should be:

`-r <executable> <arg> ...`

This works:

```
dbxtool -r /home/user/mybinaryfile
```

But if I add an argument like this:

```
dbxtool -r /home/user/mybinaryfile -s1
```

or like this:

`dbxtool -r /home/user/mybinaryfile '-s1'`

I get the following error:

```
dbxtool: Unrecognized option '-s1'
```

The argument is an argument to the executable not to dbxtool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in this link: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8530395

\\-s1 worked for me but "'-s1'" didn't.